# php does not load ini file

Tags: php, apache

I think this has been solved many times here but i have not found proper answer.

I installed `apache 2.4.9 x64 VC11, PHP5.5 x64 thread-safe VC11`. Then I tried to install phpmyadmin but I got error.

```
mbstring library is not enabled
```

So i uncommented it in php.ini file. My php.ini file is located in c:/php/. I added this line to my 
`httpd.conf` file:

```
#configure the path to php.ini
PHPIniDir "c:/php/"
```

to set `php.ini` file path.

```
phpinfo()
```

says it loaded the file from `c:/php`. But the library mbstring is still not loaded so I can't use phpmyadmin it's not just about phpmyadmin its about I can't use any libraries that are not default installed.

And yes I tried to restart apache...and not just once :p. it still doesn't work I'm hopeless. Please help me solve this.

Comment: Can't you write English sentences? Or is there another reason it's necessary to write so much `...`

Comment: Cant you read? "Hello and sorry for my english" and i think this site is not grammar help site.........

Comment: Even if you are not very good at English there's no sense in typing so many `...`.

Comment: well sorry i wont do it again

Comment: and thank you for editing my post to be more "prettier". I will learn these options. I just need to solve my issue asap so i can work.

Answer (score -1):

Ok, so after another while of hard brainstorming i figured it out. I have never had to set this but now.

Everything you have to do(check) is set the path to extension dir in your php.ini

look for line:

```
; On windows:
extension_dir = "c:\php\ext"
```

just change the path where are your extension located. If is this line commented with `;` just uncomment it restart apache and you are good to go. Hope this help someone else too.